# Use the Revit native file language instead of English when converting properties from Revit to IFC

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I've been using for a long time the Model Derivative API from Autodesk Forge to (successfully) export Revit files to IFC.

However, I notice that even when the original Revit files are saved with the French version of the software (namely, Revit FRA), the properties (e.g. `Données d'identification`) are exported in English (`Identity Data`), and I see no option in the Model Derivative API `translate` to force using the native language.

Does someone have an idea on how to do that (if it is feasible)? I have searched on the official documentation and tried modifying the parameters mentioned for the conversion (see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change)), but with no success so far.

Of course the same issue can be of interest for those exporting to other formats than IFC, or other languages than French.

Thanks!

Comment: The expected behavior of translating RVT file with MD is that all the properties would be exported using the last saved language of the RVT file itself. If this is not the case I can submit a report to the team. Also, when you say "the properties ... are exported in English", are the "properties" in properties database or in IFC file itself?

Comment: @JaimeRosales we have the same issue (kind of). The case is: we have .rvt model created in the German version of Revit (property names after trnalsation in Model derivative API are in German), then we are running the design automation API to somehow process the model and get it back. If we 'translate' the resulting model with Model derivative API property names are in English.

Comment: @YuryApanasik I think this might be related to the version of Revit running in DA, You might have to include a saving mechanism in your workitem that also addresses language would be my guess, check this from Jeremy - https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/02/multiple-language-resx-resource-files.html

Comment: @JaimeRosales Thank you for your reply. What I observe is that exporting to IFC the same Revit file by means of Autodesk Revit 2020 FRA (French) leads to a different result than with the MD API, for Revit properties like "Materials and Finishes", "Identity Data", "Constraints", "Dimensions", etc., so it seems the expected behavior you mentioned (last language saved) does not work here. I'd be grateful if you can report it to the team (at least maybe clarify the API documentation?). Meanwhile I'll check Jeremy' post. Thanks again.

Comment: ok I added the report of the problem, the functionality should be what got described. you can request an update about issue rvtlmv-1950 to forge.help@autodesk.com in the future. If I see any progress I will add it here.

Comment: OK, thanks @JaimeRosales. I will note the question as solved once this is implemented.

Comment: @rajan_brussels any chance you have a non-confidential file to reproduce the issue in our side? If you do can you send it to me directly jaime.rosales.duque@autodesk.com Thanks

Comment: @JaimeRosales: I've just sent you the mail with all the files necessary to reproduce the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After verification and interaction with Autodesk Forge support team (thanks @JaimeRosales!), it seems that the Revit file used *was* saved in the ENU language (contrarily to my belief); however, since it was opened and exported to IFC with the FRA version, the properties were also exported in French, even if the file itself was still in ENU.

Well, anyway, the conclusion to remember is that the expected behavior of the ModelDerivative API (namely: using the language of the last saving of the Revit file) is observed.